# Expression for the form $F^k\wedge \omega^{n-k}$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a holomorphic Hermitian vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold. Let us write the curvature as follows
$$F=\sum_{i,j}dz_i\wedge d\bar{z}_j\otimes f_{ij}$$
where $f_{ij}\in End(E)$ such that $f_{ij}^*=f_{ji}$. The Kahler form writes
$$\omega=i\sum_jdz_j\wedge d\bar{z}_j.$$
I am trying to find a formula for the form
$$F^k\wedge \omega^{n-k}\in\Omega^{n,n}(X,End(E)),$$
in other word an endomorphism $g\in End(E)$ such that
$$F^k\wedge \omega^{n-k}=\omega^n\otimes g.$$
In particular I want to know whether $g^*=g$.

Comment: $g$ is the trace of the matrix of $k \times k$ minors if the matrix of $F$, up to some real constant. From that you can answer your question.